# providing timeout execution for a Spring AOP Aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-async

How I can provide a timeout execution to a Spring AOP Aspect ?

The **logger** method of **MyAspect** shouldn't take more time execution than 30 seconds, if not i would want to stop the method execution. How i can do this ?

**MyAspect Code :**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {

     @Autowired
     private myService myService;

     @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* xxxxx*(..))", returning = "paramOut")
     public void logger(final JoinPoint jp, Object paramOut){
         Event event = (Event) paramOut;
         myService.save(event);
     }
}
```

**myService Interface :**

```
public interface myService {
    void save(Event event);
}
```

**myServiceImpl :**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class myServiceImpl implements myService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void save(Event event) {
        entityManager.persist(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, paste your code into the question

Comment: @LajosArpad done !, what i want to do is : avoid that the logger method of my Aspect takes an unlimited time execution. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using asynchronous logging, then it can take however long it needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `java.util.concurrent.Future` to check the timeout. See next example:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* xxxxx*(..))", returning = "paramOut")
public void logger(final JoinPoint jp, Object paramOut){
     Event event = (Event) paramOut;

     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

     Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
         public Void call() throws Exception {
            myService.save(event);
            return null;
        }
    });

    try
    {
        future.get(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e){
       //do something or log it
    } finally {
       future.cancel(true);
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, it looks like right, but can you plz explain it ? what about if the Call method take more than 30 seconds, it will be interrupted ?